Difference of sets and read access violation
I'm trying to find a difference of sets (I use vectors but idea is the same: arr1 \ arr2) using inline assembly in VS. But I can't get rid of the following error: "An exception was thrown: read access violation. ptr1 was 0xFFFFFFD7". And for some reason it is always 0xFFFFFFD7. It's worth noting that the error appears after I perform deleting. I'd be extremely grateful if you could help me figure this out.
std::vector<int> arr1 = {8, 3};
std::vector<int> arr2 = {7, 8};
int* ptr1 = arr1.data() - 1;
int size1 = arr1.size();
int* ptr2 = arr2.data() - 1;
int size2 = arr2.size();
int numberOfDeletes = 0;
__asm {
    mov ebx, ptr2
    mov edx, 0
    _array2:
        mov eax, ptr1
        mov ecx, size1
        cmp edx, size2
        je _out
        add ebx, 4
        mov esi, dword ptr[ebx]
    _comparing:
        add eax, 4
        cmp dword ptr [eax], esi
        je _delete
        loop _comparing
        inc edx
        jmp _array2
    _delete:
        mov edi, eax
        add edi, 4
        mov ebp, dword ptr [edi]
        mov dword ptr [eax], ebp
        add eax, 4
        loop _array2
    _out:
        add eax, 4
        mov ptr1, eax
        mov eax, numberOfDeletes
        sub size1, eax
}

I tried using the lea commmand like this: lea eax, arr1[0], but it doesn't work as I expect it to because the pointer from arr1.data() and the adress I get using lea are different.

mov ebp, dword ptr [edi] clobbers EBP. EBP is used to compute offsets within the stack frame to access local variables. Once clobbered future references to the locals will fail. Rather than use EBP use ESI as a temporary register. In your code ESI is used as a temporary scratch register already so you can reuse it to replace mov ebp, dword ptr [edi] mov dword ptr [eax], ebp with mov esi, dword ptr [edi] mov dword ptr [eax], esi. I'm a bit surprised the MSVC compiler didn't give you a warning about your inline assembly clobbering EBP.

You have other problems besides that issue but I think you should be able to debug the rest.
